# C# Linq check if value exists

Tags: c#, linq

I have a database structured like this:

**Detector:**

```
DetectorID    SiteID    TrackID
  1401         1400        2
  1402         1400        2
  1601         1600        2
  1602         1600        2
```

**DetectorStatus:**

```
DetectorStatusID    DetectorID    DateTime    DetectorModeID    Status
       1               1601       TimeStamp        2             0.86
       2               1602       TimeStamp        2             0.84
```

Now i have a filter which let me see the Detectors based on their DetectorMode.

**Code:**

```
var query = loadOperation.Entities; //Define the query

if (ShowAtlas == false && ShowPhoenix == false || ShowAtlas == true && ShowPhoenix == true)
{
    if (filterany1.IsChecked == true)
    {
        query = query.OrderBy(d => d.SiteName);
    }
    if (filterok1.IsChecked == true)
    {
        query = query.Where(d => d.Detectors.Count(t => t.DetectorStatus.Count(a => a.DetectorModeID == 2) > 0) > 0);
    }
    if (filtermaintenance1.IsChecked == true)
    {
        query = query.Where(d => d.Detectors.Count(t => t.DetectorStatus.Count(a => a.DetectorModeID == 3 || a.DetectorModeID == 4 || a.DetectorModeID == 5) > 0) > 0);
    }
    if (filternotworking.IsChecked == true)
    {
        query = query.Where(d => d.Detectors.Count(t => t.DetectorStatus.Count(a => a.DetectorModeID == 6 || a.DetectorModeID == 7) > 0) > 0);
    }
}
```

Now, when a detector is Unknow. It wont be in the **DetectorStatus** table. As given in the example. DetectorID's **1401** and **1402** are unknown.

When i filter on:

```
if (filternotworking.IsChecked == true)
{
    query = query.Where(d => d.Detectors.Count(t => t.DetectorStatus.Count(a => a.DetectorModeID == 6 || a.DetectorModeID == 7) > 0) > 0);
}
```

I also want to order on the unknown detector types.
How do i achieve this?
Because right now i count the results. But if there is nothing, it wont show anything.

For the filter.

The DetectorModes tell me what the status of the detector is. For example:

2 = System Okay
7 = Offline

However, When a detector is not in the **DetectorStatus** table. It obviously does not have any values in this table. 
When this is the case, the mode of the detector is Unknown.
And i want to be able to filter on the Unknow system types.

Comment: How can you filter on the ones that aren't in `DetectorStatus` they don't have `DetectorStatus.Count`

Comment: It would help if you would post your expected result includign data based on your example source data.

Comment: I want to filter on the Detectors. But if the don't exist in the DetectorStatus table, their DetectorModeID is unknown. When it is unknown/does not exist in that table. I want to be able to filter on it.

Comment: in general case you need to avoid work with quantity for avoiding null reference.

Comment: Made an edit @MightyBadaboom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this:

```
query = query.Where(d => d.Detectors.Count(t => t.DetectorStatus.Count() == 0) > 0);
```

But I would prefer `Any()` instead of `Count()>0`, if available.

Comment: This works! However, is there a way to combine it with the DetectorModes 6 and 7?      **query = query.Where(d => d.Detectors.Count(t => t.DetectorStatus.Count(a => a.DetectorModeID == 6 || a.DetectorModeID == 7) > 0) > 0);**

Comment: query = query.Where(d => d.Detectors.Count(t => t.DetectorStatus.Count() == 0||t.DetectorStatus.Count(a => a.DetectorModeID == 6 || a.DetectorModeID == 7) > 0) > 0);